# Help me deciper "trying to do this XX that honestly?"

Tags: meaning

> Listen Chris, in the past I talked A LOT of shit concerning your vids(and in reality, who the hell was I to talk about someone else), but the reality is- you knew what the hell you were doing, and even I can accept that while somewhat campy and corny your work isn't half bad on a whole. What I recommend, is you do your own thing, and ***forget about trying to do this on screen skit crap that honestly?***
>   It wore out it's welcome ages ago. Most people tolerate it, simply to get to the good stuff, and that's a knowledge and interesting things to say about the game/media in question. You clearly came back with the ability to take the piss out of not only the game, retro nostalgia, and yourself no less, so yeah-

What does the emphasized part mean?

> forget about trying to do this on screen skit crap that honestly?

I've read this numerous times now, very slowly, without being able to decipher it.

"on screen skit crap that honestly"? What? It really bothers me that people force me to waste my time and energy just because they can't be bothered to spend half a second correcting whatever typo or error has turned that sentence into utter world salad.

Comment: -1 because using that word "retard" wasn't that respectful.

Comment: Sometimes people just write/speak nonsense.

Comment: I read the problematic part as **forget about trying to do this on screen skit crap that - honestly! - wore out its welcome ages ago**. That is, 'honestly' is an intensifier for what is about to follow.

Answer (score 0):

- "forget about trying to do": an imperative request
- "this on screen skit crap": skits performed on a screen for which the speaker has an editorial quality judgement
- "that honestly?": a verbal construction of a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), utilized to introduce the speaker's direct opinion in the following line.

Maybe it would read more clearly as:

> What I recommend, is you do your own thing, and forget about trying to do this on screen skit crap (that honestly? It wore out it's welcome ages ago).

Answer (score 0):

forget about [[trying to do [this on screen skit crap]] that honestly]?

this on screen skit crap = this crap that people do when acting in an on-screen skit

that honestly = degree modifier (how honestly -> that honestly = **so** honestly)

? -> indicates suggestion, not question

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be reworded as "Give up on incorporating skits in your video.  In my honest view, they became tiresome long ago."